# Reactjs redirecting from a child event

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I am working on a reactjs application and I have a component that will provide a visualisation to represent the users. The admin will be able to select a user - and the id of the user comes back to the parent shell - but I am having issues trying to redirect the url to go to that particular user --  doesn't appear to do anything.

So in this case obj.data will contain just a number.

```
var UserExplorer = React.createClass({

    setParentState(obj) {
      console.log("obj", obj.data);

      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        this.setState({
          [key]: obj[key]
        });
      });

      <Redirect push to="/user/2"/>

      //this.navigate("/user/2")
      //<Redirect to="/user/2" />
    },

    render: function () {
      var data = null;

      return (
        <div className="component-container">

              <ViewedMeChart 
                  width="250" 
                  height="250"  
                  data={data}
                  setParentState={this.setParentState} />

        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: See this to navigate dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108 You can't just call Redirect, you have to return it i.e render it

Comment: "this.props.history.push('/home');" - didn't work - comes up with an undefined. Why doesn't the redirect work in this context. Want to try and ensure its a smooth experience.

Comment: you need to make use of withRouter to access history, see the answer completely, as I said, you need to render Redirect which it is not

Comment: I have withRouter in place -- but this redirecting is coming from a child component.

Comment: Is withRouter used on UserExplorer, If not, either use it there or pass the router props down from parent

Comment: its got like 2-3 parents - its heavily nested

Comment: Then make use of withRouter for UserExplorer itself